MicroPython TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len() When Using ubluetooth on ESP32
I'm working with an ESP32 module running MicroPython and I'm encountering a persistent TypeError when attempting to use the ubluetooth module for BLE functionality. The error occurs when I try to register BLE services.
Here's the simplest version of the code that still produces the error:
from ubluetooth import BLE, UUID, FLAG_READ, FLAG_WRITE

_BLE_UUID = UUID('12345678-1234-5678-1234-56789abcdef0')
_BLE_CHAR_UUID = UUID('abcdef01-1234-5678-1234-56789abcdef0')

ble = BLE()
ble.active(True)

services = (
    (_BLE_UUID, (
        (_BLE_CHAR_UUID, FLAG_READ | FLAG_WRITE, 32),
    )),
)

service_handle, char_handle = ble.gatts_register_services(services)[0]

print("Service registered")


When I run this code, I get the following error:
MPY: soft reboot 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "<stdin>", line 15, in <module> 
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len() 


I've attempted to simplify the code to isolate the issue, but the error persists. I've confirmed that the firmware is up to date and have tried running the code on a different ESP32 device with the same result.
I'm looking for any insights into what might be causing this error and how to resolve it. Could it be an issue with the MicroPython firmware or the ubluetooth module? Has anyone else encountered this, and how did you resolve it?
nothing works with bluetooth on esp32
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

According to the Micropython Documentation ,
return values will be like this,
( (hr,), (tx, rx,), ) = bt.gatts_register_services(SERVICES)

However,In your function you are goint to access the first tuple as two values
service_handle, char_handle = ble.gatts_register_services(services)[0]

So try to access as one value like given in the documentation

'code' from ubluetooth import BLE, UUID, FLAG_READ, FLAG_WRITE
_BLE_UUID = UUID('12345678-1234-5678-1234-56789abcdef0')
_BLE_CHAR_UUID = UUID('abcdef01-1234-5678-1234-56789abcdef0')
ble = BLE()
ble.active(True)
services = (
(_BLE_UUID, (
(_BLE_CHAR_UUID, FLAG_READ | FLAG_WRITE, 32),
)),
)
result = ble.gatts_register_services(services)
((service_handle,), (char_handle,),) = result
print("Service registered") 'code' Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 15, in 
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
